# How to resize a canvas with the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I would like to have this canvas resize when the browser size changes whatsoever so that it matches the browser size so that the background fits better. I have tried using a function to resize the canvas whenever the browser size changes but the canvas size never changed.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>About RatherChaotic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/pfp.png">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.terminal/js/jquery.terminal.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/jquery.terminal@2.x.x/css/jquery.terminal.min.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body class="home">
    <div class="background">
        <script src="assets/js/background.js" type="module"></script>
        <canvas id="background_canvas">Cannot Render Canvas</canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="foreground">
        <script src="assets/js/app.js" type="module"></script>
        <a href="https://github.com/RatherChaotic"><img id="pfp" src="assets/images/pfp.png" alt="My Profile Picture" width="256" height="256"></a>
        <h1 id="username">RatherChaotic</h1>
        <p id="wia"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="terminal"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Monocraft;
    src: url("../Monocraft.ttf");
}

body {
    height: auto;
}

.background canvas{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    z-index: -1;
}


.foreground {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    fill-opacity: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    color: #FFF;


}

.foreground #pfp {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;


}

.foreground #username {
    font-family: Monocraft, monospace;
    font-size: xx-large;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    top:30px;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}

.foreground #wia {
    position: relative;
    font-family: Monocraft, monospace;
    font-size: large;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    top:40px;
    width:100%;
}

#terminal {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    width: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

background.js

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('background_canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const katakana = 'アァカサタナハマヤャラワガザダバパイィキシチニヒミリヰギジヂビピウゥクスツヌフムユュルグズブヅプエェケセテネヘメレヱゲゼデベペオォコソトノホモヨョロヲゴゾドボポヴッン';
const latin = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const nums = '0123456789';

const alphabet = katakana + latin + nums;

const fontSize = 16;
const columns = canvas.width/fontSize;

const rainDrops = [];

for( let x = 0; x < columns; x++ ) {
    rainDrops[x] = 1;
}

const draw = () => {
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.fillStyle = '#0F0';
    context.font = fontSize + 'px monocraft';

    for(let i = 0; i < rainDrops.length; i++)
    {
        const text = alphabet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length));
        context.fillText(text, i*fontSize, rainDrops[i]*fontSize);

        if(rainDrops[i]*fontSize > canvas.height && Math.random() > 0.975){
            rainDrops[i] = 0;
        }
        rainDrops[i]++;
    }
};

setInterval(draw, 30);
```

Comment: @Izanagi css and html5 canvas's don't really pair together well as when you resize with css something will go off-screen

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that you used a function to change the canvas when the window changed, im not sure if you have tried and event listener but here is the code i think might solve your problem.

```js
let columns = canvas.width/fontSize;
let rainDrops = Array(columns).fill(1);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    columns = canvas.width/fontSize;
    rainDrops = Array(columns).fill(1);
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you. I don't think I changed the raindrops at all when I tried to add the event listener before and I think that's where my problem came from.

Comment: canvas should always stay at some reasonable size otherwise performance might suffer.